# How to make dynamic loader using javascript php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on Php, Right now i am getting data from database using multiple queries, In database there maybe be 10 records or maybe 10,000 record, So i want to use progress bar which should show how percentage (%) query complete (estimated time), Because as i said there maybe few records or maybe thousands of record,Is this possible to create dynamic loader (progress bar) ?

Comment: Please provide more background details on your problem. Tell readers what you found through your research, what you have already tried, and why it didn't meet your needs. This will help readers better understand your problem and avoid giving answers that you have already tried.

Comment: @Panda understand sir, but i research a lot but not found anything regarding this, right now i want to know is this possible or not , if yes then i just want to know steps for complete this task

Answer (score 0):

With ajax, you can get the number of rows and calculete a number to sum to the progressbar, after that you shoud call with other ajax method to a php function which has a query with limit x (this number x shoud be pass by ajax param).
After that, in the response of ajax, you can sum the % of the progressbar.

[Progressbar bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/progress/)